# declaring scope resolution operator without including standart header

Tags: c++, scope-resolution-operator

I Learn C++ programing and I was a beginner, and my question is can I use scope resolution operator without including Standart library? can someone help me?.

Comment: Yes you can. Did you encounter problems when you tried?

Comment: yes, but i got an error message

Comment: Show the code and the error; in other words, a [mcve]. I can assure you the issue is not caused by using the scope resolution operator without including standard headers.

Comment: that said, cin is not member of std

Comment: Well, you don't get this error because you are using the scope resolution operator, but because you are using a **name** defined in the standard library, without including the header where that name is defined. `#include <iostream>`

Comment: If you declared your own classes, namespaces, you are free to use the scope resolution operator to your heart's content. But if you need to reference classes and templates in the C++ library, then you certainly need to `#include` the appropriate headers.

Comment: The scope resolution operator is part of the core language, not reliant on any part of the standard library.     If you want to use parts of the standard library (like things with names in the `std` namespace) then you are reliant on the library - the scope resolution operator does not allow you to use parts of the library if you haven't included relevant standard headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope resolution operator is as the name says, an operator, and is not part of any library but rather the basic syntax of the C++ language. It's hard to tell exactly what your issue is based off your question, but when you don't know what you're doing wrong it can be hard to find the right words to ask. Try reading Tutorials Point's article on namespaces, I find their tutorials very helpful and approachable for beginners https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm